# Php curl error Url not found on this server

Tags: php, url, curl

I am working on core php.
I am requesting a URL by curl. This is working on my development server but same thing are not working on live server.

Below is my Code:

---

```
$url = "http://www.streamatemodels.com/login.php";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'submitted=1&g=&sausr='.urlencode('username').'&sapwd='.urlencode('password').'');

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$error = curl_errno($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);  
print_r($result);
```

Please help me if anyone have solution.

---

Update

I checked this with new username and password but same things happen. Its working on my development server but not working on live and local host.

Comment: Are both of your environments using the same versions of PHP and libcurl? Check out the [cURL requirements for PHP](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/curl.requirements.php).

Comment: You need to be more specific than, "It's not working." What is not working? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: You should output your url and verify it is the same, if it is and I am assuming you are getting a 404 error, note that the server could have blocked your production server and not your development server. Is this your own server? If it is a 3rd party it could have simply blocked you for making too many request, sometimes I have made this mistake and unwanted a loop in my application has behaved like a DOS attack.

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'submitted=1&g=&sausr='.urlencode('username').'&sapwd='.urlencode('password').'');
```

should be changed to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'submitted=1&g=&sausr='.urlencode($username).'&sapwd='.urlencode($password).'');
```

If it still doesn't work try to create the query-string outside of curl_setopt:

```
 $params = 'submitted=1&g=&sausr='.urlencode($username).'&sapwd='.urlencode($password).'';
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
```

Another advise: it's better practice to use [http_build_query($params)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

**UPDATE**

I had the time to check the code, and it works fine on my local host (meaning: check your username/password!):

[image]

Comment: I think (s)he was obfuscating the actual values, not referring to variables. In any case, you're using single quotes -- if they are variables, they won't get interpreted.

Comment: @AlexHowansky good catch - fixed. And you might be right - which is why I added another couple of things (s)he can try ;)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
I follow step told by you but getting same not working.